# Removing occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: java, string, substring, character

In the code below, I am trying to find each occurrence of 'C' in the string "CACA", remove it, then add the newly generated string to an array list. However, each occurrence should be removed once from the original string, which is "CACA" and once from each new string generated.

So the output should be as follows: [CACA, ACA, CAA, AA]

My code returns: [CACA, ACA, AA], so what am I missing?

```
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        array.add("CACA");
        String s = "C";
        //ArrayList<String> newArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // create a new array to hold the new elements

        for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array.get(i).length(); j++) {
                if(s.equals(String.valueOf(array.get(i).charAt(j)))) {
                    if(array.get(i).length() == 1) {
                        array.add("e");
                    } else {
                        String a = String.valueOf(array.get(i).charAt(j));
                        int index = array.get(i).indexOf(a);
                        if(index == 0) {
                            String newStr = array.get(i).substring(1);
                            array.add(newStr);
                        } else if(index == array.get(i).length() - 1) {
                            String newStr = array.get(i).substring(0, array.get(i).length() - 1);
                            array.add(newStr);
                        } else {
                            String newStr = array.get(i).substring(0, index) + array.get(i).substring(index + 1);
                            array.add(newStr);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(newArray);
        // add the new elements to the original array after the loop has finished
        //array.addAll(newArray);

        HashSet<String> setWithoutDuplicates = new HashSet<String>(array);
        array.clear();
        array.addAll(setWithoutDuplicates);
        System.out.print(array);
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through your code with a debugger and dump the contents of your array at each step? Ideally, you should know where your problems lies before you post a question. If you debug properly, 9 times out of 10, you'll be able to fix things without outside assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem with your code;

You start with an array list containing the string "CACA". Then you remove the first "C" and add the new string "ACA" to the array list **twice**.

```
int index = array.get(i).indexOf(a);
```

This code returns index 0 two times and causes duplicate strings in your array list.

> The indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence of
> specified character(s) in a string.

Your code never finds the index of second "C" in the string. So "CAA" doesn't get added to the array list. And the above code is unnecessary because **you can already find the index of the char stored at the variable "j"**.

The for loop runs on the newly added strings "ACA" (both of them) and the "C" in the middle gets deleted. "AA" is added to the list twice. The process ends.

This is the solution:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
array.add("CACA");
String charToSearch = "C";

for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.get(i).length(); j++) {

        String currentCharAsString = String.valueOf(array.get(i).charAt(j));
        if(charToSearch.equals(currentCharAsString)) {
            if(array.get(i).length() == 1) {
                array.add("e");
            } else {
                String newString = array.get(i).substring(0, j) + array.get(i).substring(j + 1);
                //Check if the string is already added to the array list to prevent duplicates
                if(!array.contains(newString))
                    array.add(newString);

            }
        }
    }
}
System.out.print(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that it doesn't remove all occurrences of the character 'C' from the original string and from each newly generated string. Instead, it only removes the first occurrence of 'C' it finds in the original string and then generates new strings. Subsequent occurrences of 'C' in the new strings are not removed. To fix this, you can modify the inner loop to keep track of the index of the last occurrence of 'C' that was removed from the original string, and then remove only the next occurrence after that index in each new string generated.

However, it's worth noting that this approach only works for strings of length 1 and is not very flexible. It's better to write more generic code that can handle any string and character. As an alternative, I have written a function that does exactly what you are trying to achieve:

```
public static ArrayList<String> deleteOccurrences(String input,char occ) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < result.get(i).length(); j++)
            if (result.get(i).charAt(j) == occ && !result.contains(result.get(i).substring(0, j) + result.get(i).substring(j + 1)))
                result.add(result.get(i).substring(0, j) + result.get(i).substring(j + 1));
    return result;
}
```

you can call this function like this (if you want to test it):

```
 ArrayList<String> result = deleteOccurrences("CACA",'C');
 System.out.println(result);
```